# How is chosen the output of .par.map(...).seq and how to control it?

Tags: scala, collections, parallel-processing

I often use `.par.map(...).seq`. However, I always want to know the actual output type of my methods: which Seq implementation and be sure it won't generate strange behaviors down the line, such as what can happen with view or stream.

So
 1) What is the real output type of `.par.map(...).seq`?

I tried in the shell, and it was a Vector for list and range input, and an ArraySeq for array input. But by looking in the source, I could not understand how or where this was chosen (the trait hierarchy is too complex to follow).

2) Is there a way to control it, like using canbuildfrom?

I tried to use explicit canbuildfrom directly in the .map, but this actually break the .par behaviors, it seems.

Note: I ask those questions to avoid doing a safe copy, like using `.toVector` which would work obviously.